# IN ms project, sub project tasks are not showing up in sprint task board

Tags: ms-project

I added multiple sub projects to my current master project. I dont see the sub project tasks in sprint task board though I assigned sprints to tasks and "show on board" is yes. THe tasks from the master project show up but not the sub project tasks.

Comment: As this question is not about programming, but rather how to use Microsoft Project, it belongs on the [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) site.

Comment: oh..k I posted in PM site -https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/31224/in-ms-project-sub-project-tasks-are-not-showing-up-in-sprint-task-board . Thanks!